# read text file in C++

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a question regarding what to do with `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` etc. when reading a text file in C++. The problem exists when I do the following sequence of operations:

```
int k;
f>>k;
string line;
getline(f,line);
```

for an input file with something like

```
1
abc
```

I have to put a `f.get()` in order to read off the ending `"\n"` after `f>>k`. I even have to do `f.get()` twice if I have `"\r\n"`.

What is an elegant way of reading file like this if I mix `>>` with `getline`?

Thank you.

**Edit**
Also, I wonder if there is any convenient way to automatically detect the given file has an end-of-line char `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to fiddle a little bit to `>>` and `getline` to work happily together.   In general, reading something from a stream with the `>>` operator will not discard any following whitspaces (new line characters).

The usual approach to solve this is with the `istream::ignore` function following `>>` - telling it to discard every character up to and including the next newline.  (Only useful if you actually want to discard every character up to the newline though).

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "type a number: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    std::cout << "type a string: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, s );
    std::cout << s << " " << n << std::endl;
}
```

*edit* (I realise you mentioned files in the question, but hopefully it goes without saying that std::cin is completely interchangable with an ifstream)

Comment: Thanks! Please see my edit: so how to automatically write the statement `std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );` given sometimes I have "\r\n" as the ending characters?

Comment: @QiangLi it ignores **all** characters up-to and including the `\n` character.  it doesn't matter what those characters are, there's nothing special about putting an `\r` in front of it so "\r\n" will be treated the same way as "\n" or "helloworld\t\n".

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach would be to pre-process the data file using `tr` (assuming that you use Linux) to remove `\r` and then use `getline()`.